# How to select the options from the list and use them to form array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a feature in which I want all the selected options from the dropdown list to be transferred into a new dropdown list.

My logic is

1: I want to make an array of the selected options

2: then transform that array into a new dropdown list

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check code below

```js
var firstDropdownList = document.getElementById("ddlFirst");
var secondDropdownList = document.getElementById("ddlSecond");
firstDropdownList.addEventListener("change", () => {
  secondDropdownList.length = 0; // clear the list
  Array.from(firstDropdownList.selectedOptions).forEach((o) => {
    secondDropdownList.options.add(new Option(o.text, o.value));
  })
});
```

```html
<select id="ddlFirst" multiple>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Sever</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSecond" multiple>

</select>
```